# Correct mistakenly changing mouse select to left button

Tags: interface

When I installed 2.81 I mistakenly chose select with left button. I use the mouse with my left hand and actually want to select with right button. My Preferences>Input does not have a provision to change this. My download is named /blender-2.81a-linux-glibc217-x86_64. Is there a work around?

(I have two previous versions of Blender installed and when I used them I selected with the left button.)

[image: Preferences>Input]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Head over to the *Keymap* tab and you'll find the select options under *Preferences*
[image]